# Is there a way to get an elements position relative to the bottom of vewport?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm looking for this specifically ( because of circumstancec it can only be done like this ) and i need to get the distance the bottom of a div is in relation to the bottom of the viewport ( like 20px would mean that the bottom of the div is 20px above the bottom of the viewport and negative values would be how far the user has to scroll to get to the bottom of the div ).

**Update:**

Please no jquery

Here is a photo to maybe better understand
[image]

Comment: Please post your working code or what you have tried. [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I would if i had any. Cant think of any way to do it.

Comment: Could you post an image then of what you are looking for?

Comment: @scoopzilla will try. gimme a sec to sketch it

Comment: @scoopzilla Here you go image uploaded :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get the bottom position of both the element you want to monitor and the window (viewport) by adding the top position to the height, then subtract the bottom value of the element from the bottom value of the window.

```js
var foo = document.getElementById('foo');

window.addEventListener('scroll',function() {
  var fooTop = foo.offsetTop,
    fooHeight = foo.offsetHeight,
    fooBottom = fooTop + fooHeight,
    st = window.scrollY,
    wh = window.innerHeight,
    wb = st + wh,
    distance = wb - fooBottom;
  console.log(distance);
})
```

```css
section {
  min-height: 100vh;
}
#foo {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<section></section>
<section id="foo"></section>
<section></section>
```

Comment: Oh i'm sorry i forgot to mention no Jquery please :(

Comment: Thanks dude thats exactly what i needed :)

Comment: @TheTruth word up! np :)